# Css Not applying after hosting on iis 7.5 with pipeline mode = integrated

Tags: asp.net, css, iis-7

I have a ASP.Net web application developed on visual studio 2010 and it is working fine on local machine. When i hosted it to IIS 7.5 with pipeline mode= Integrated, the css is not applying on the Web pages. I had gone through Control Panel -> Program and features ->Turns Windows feature on and off -> iis -> www ->common Http features and enabled the static content also but still the css is not applying. 
Please help me to fix this issue and thanks in advance for the solution .

Comment: Try using an HTTP debugger such as Fiddler, and see what errors are being returned over the wire when requesting your CSS resources. http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: How are you referencing your CSS files?

Comment: I am getting same problem again, have you got any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added user Everyone to the css folder and given him permission and then it is working fine for me now.